# What's happening in this JavaScript foo(); function?

Tags: javascript

Hey I am not able to understand this JavaScript code properly:

```
 foo(i) {
     if (i < 0)
         return;

     console.log('begin: ' + i);

     foo(i - 1);
     console.log('after: ' + i);
 }

 foo(3);
```

Output

```
begin: 3
begin: 2
begin: 1
begin: 0
after: 0
after: 1 
after: 2
after: 3
```

So I know what's happened inside the code for first four output but not able to understand what's happened inside the code for last four output pls someone explain this code in details for last four output it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: It is a self-invoking function. It returns when the input/counter reaches the 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this example shows the recursive function call as it executes :

```
 function foo(i)
  {
    if(i<0)
    return;
    console.log('begin: ' +i); // Line 1
    foo(i-1);  // Line 2
    console.log('after: ' +i);  // Line 3
  }
  foo(3);
```

What happens is first you call Line 1, then call the function again at Line 2, and then Line 3

So the execution stack looks like this

```
console.log('begin: ' +3); // Line 1
foo(2);  // Line 2
console.log('after: ' +3);  // Line 3
```

Now next Line 2 would again be converted to :

```
console.log('begin: ' +3); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +2); // Line 1
foo(1); // Line 2
console.log('after: ' +2);  // Line 3

console.log('after: ' +3);  // Line 3
```

and so forth

```
console.log('begin: ' +3); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +2); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +1); // Line 1
foo(0); // Line 2
console.log('after: ' +1);  // Line 3
console.log('after: ' +2);  // Line 3

console.log('after: ' +3);  // Line 3
```

And final iteration :

```
console.log('begin: ' +3); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +2); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +1); // Line 1
console.log('begin: ' +0); // Line 1
foo(-1) // Line 2 for negative value, we are exiting the recursion.
console.log('after: ' +0);  // Line 3
console.log('after: ' +1);  // Line 3
console.log('after: ' +2);  // Line 3

console.log('after: ' +3);  // Line 3
```

Comment: How the value of `i` is increasing in `console.log('after)`

Comment: Its not increasing. If you see... The value passed to foo is decreasing and that is coming before the second console so the decreased value is getting printed first.

Comment: so where these values of  `i` is getting stored before consoling